# map() not working as expected because of React.StrictMode

Tags: reactjs

first of all, I'm a newbie to react, and I'm using `React 16.13.1`.I have a functional component called `chart.js` for this component am getting data as props from the parent component which is a class-based one. I want to convert the data I'm getting from the parent so I used the map method.becuse of react strict mood all the components running twice. this `map()` running twice which will give me the wrong data.so I removed `<React.StrictMode/>`.then I got the result I expected.what is the correct way to solve this.I only use useState() in this `chart.js`.

```
  const chart = (props) =>{
    
    const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);
    let convertedArray = [];
    
      if(props.chartData){
           convertedArray = props.chartData.chartData.map(item => {
             if(format(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd').toString() === item.date){
                 item.date = 'today'
             }
              else
               item.date = format(new Date(item.date),'MM/dd');
             return item;
           })
         }
    
    return(
       // returning my jsx
      )
    }
  export default chart;
```

Comment: There is typo in props..

Comment: const chart = (porps) =>{

Comment: It looks like you're mutating the prop. Try cloning each item. Ie: ```{...item, date: 'today'}```

Comment: it was a mistake when I typed the code here.I fixed that.

Comment: @GitGitBoom can you give me a bit more clarification.it would be very helpfull

Comment: You're mutating the item when performing ```item.date = 'NEWVALUE'``` so it is already changed when you map it the second time. You can instead do ```return {...item, date: 'today'} ``` and ```return {...item, date: format(new Date(item.date),'MM/dd')}``` in either condition. That way your creating a new object for every item.

Comment: @GitGitBoom got the point